# Matlab Run Time Compiler .exe

Tags: matlab

I'm know that its a beginner question but after I'm install the Matlab Compiler Runtime how can i run the matlab compiler from DOS?
I have the directory `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime`
Where is the compiler .exe or something like that?
Thanks

Comment: You generate the exe from MATLAB using compiler. Then run the generated exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you actually have the MATLAB compiler as well. The Compiler Runtime and the compiler are two entirely different programs.

[From the help](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/), *The MATLAB Runtime is a standalone set of shared libraries that enables the execution of compiled MATLAB applications or components on computers that do not have MATLAB installed.*

Once you've compiled the exe (on a computer with MATLAB), you will move the exe to a computer without MATLAB, which has the compiler runtime installed.